# C static variables and linux fork

Tags: c, linux, memory, fork, shared-memory

Hi I created a server program that forks a new process after its accepts a socket connection.
There are several statically allocated global variables defined in the program.  My question is are these static buffers allocated twice after the fork?  Or does the fork only duplicate address space on the heap and the call stack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *entire* address space is duplicated, including all global variables and the program text.

Comment: I am working with about 10MB of ram and I am not seeing the amount of free memory drop after the fork call?  If static allocation happens at compile time then how can the fork duplicate it?

Comment: static allocation does not happen at compile time - it happens at run time, the implementation of which is left up to the C library in question but it must be done before `main`. So that memory is part of the process image, which is what fork duplicates.

Comment: @juxtapose: When you fork() a program, all that happens is that the memory used by the program is marked copy on write.  So your ram usage doesn't start going up until you start writing to memory, and then only pages you have written to come unshared.

Answer (score 8):

The whole address space is "duplicated" during `fork(2)`. It's often done with *copy-on-write* and there are more details about sharing program text and the libraries, but that is not relevant here. Both parent and child processes end up with their own copy of the static data.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` duplicates the entire process image. All of it. As such, are they allocated twice... no, they're allocated once per executable image of which there are now two, and no, if you refer to one in the parent, it will not hold the same content as that of the child unless you use shared memory.

On `static`, that keyword means this (from ISO C99):

> An object whose identifier is declared
>   with external or internal linkage, or
>   with the storage-class specifier
>   static has static storage duration.
>   Its lifetime is the entire execution
>   of the program and its stored value is
>   initialized only once, prior to
>   program startup.

Which basically means your buffer will be initialised once as part of the CRT startup routine and that space only disappears when you exit. In this case, that storage disappears when each child exits.

Answer (score 2):

Linux uses mechanism called copy-on-write. That basically means, that as long as variable is not modified parent and new process are sharing one variable. But before variable is modified it is copied and new process uses copy. It is done for performance reasons and technique is called lazy optimization. So you shouldn't worry that changing variable in one process will change it in another.