# Can I cause a Meyers singleton to reinitialize in forked child processes?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, fork

Say I have a meyers singleton

```
Data& get() {
  static Data data = initialization_work();
  return data;
}
```

that's already been used and initialized in a parent process. I then fork(2) a child process, and in the child process `data` may need to be different (ie, i'd like `initialization_work()` to rerun the first time `get()` is called in the child).

First, will `data` automatically be reinitialized in the forked child? My suspicion is no, based on my mediocre knowledge of linux (forked child VA space is a duplicate of parent mapped to physical memory copy-on-write, so i assume child process will see `data` as already initialized and won't redo `initialization_work()`) and a couple other questions ([C static variables and linux fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879294/c-static-variables-and-linux-fork#),
[C++ static variable and multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545602/c-static-variable-and-multiple-processes)).

Second, if `data` *will not* be reinitialized in the child by default, is there a way to force reinitialization the first time the child calls `get()`? If not, I can try to figure out some other pattern (and I'd really appreciate any suggestions on what pattern might fit this use case).

Comment: @MartinYork: 1. The process ID is different :-P 2. The question still stands, even if it's about the original process...

Comment: I answered before I should (so I removed it). Do you _want_ it to reinitialize even if you get a (nearly) exact copy as @MartinYork mentions?

Comment: You could save the current `pid` inside `get()` if the pid changes reset that value of `data`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, will data automatically be reinitialized in the forked child? My suspicion is no

Why just a suspicion? Indeed, nothing will be initialized. As @MartinYork mentions - you get a copy of the original process. That's the magic of forking - no need to initialize the world. The parent and the child both proceed to act differently based (almost) only on the return value of the `fork()` call.

> Second, if data will not be reinitialized in the child by default, is there a way to force reinitialization the first time the child calls get()?

That's the same question as asking about forcing a reinitialization of a singleton in the original process. Now, of course there are ways...

- You get a non-const reference to `data`, right? Well, you can [destroy it explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187398/1593077), then use [placement-new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) on that address. I'm... almost sure that's legit.
- @BenVoigt's neat alternative to the above:  Use an [`std::optional<Data>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/) singleton. It's still a sort-of-a-singleton, but you can assign `nullopt` to it, for destruction, then construct a new `Data` in place with [`std::optional::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace).
- Change the class' code to place the `data` variable somewhere more visible.
- Just drop the singleton pattern. It is unlikely you really need it. Watch:

  [Retiring the Singleton Pattern: Concrete Suggestions for What to use Instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5c7uvWe_hw)
  A talk by Peter Muldoon at CppCon'20.

Comment: Use `std::optional` to take care of all the placement-new and explicit destructor call details.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's a great idea too. Edited it in.

Comment: Seems to me whether i use std::optional or not, the child needs to know it's the child to destruct and reconstruct `data`, so I'd need to check the PID or something. is that implicitly part of your suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelCarilli: But the child process does know it's the child, based on the result of the `fork()`; that's what you check.

Comment: Right, I meant given its importance, it should be explicit in the answer for future readers. I see you added it, thanks!