# What does "statically allocated" exactly mean in libc? One per library instance? One per program instance?

Tags: c, libc, localtime, single-threaded, static-allocation

In (g)libc, for example in time and date functions like *localtime*, the manual says:

> The return value points to a statically allocated string which might
>   be overwritten by subsequent calls  to  any  of  the date  and  time
>   functions.

As far as I know, my program is single-threaded. Is it safe for me to use the "MT-Unsafe" functions like *asctime* or *localtime*?

Even if there is only 1 (g)libc library instance in the memory? (I.e. as a dynamic library.)

Does "static" mean "static to my program" (for each program instance a new buffer instance is allocated..), "static to the process" (one buffer instance per process -- [this suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879294/c-static-variables-and-linux-fork)), or static to the (libc) library (as many buffer instances as library (-fragment) instances)?

(I know about question #8694365 but mine a bit differs.)

Comment: There's no such thing as "library instance". If the C standard says you can use `localtime`, and your program adheres to the standard (i.e. doesn't uses things like threads), then you can use `localtime`. That's what the standard is for.

Comment: Can't emphasize this enough: **There's no such thing as "library instance".**

Comment: @R - this is compiler dependent. gnu has a thread unsafe version of localtime, while [Visual Studio local time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) appears to always be thread safe. DLL libraries could be considered as "one instance per system" libraries. Static libraries could be considered as "one instance per process". Windows has a per thread data area, for thread safe libraries to use as needed. I don't know how Posix systems implement this.

Comment: @R..: there can only be one instance of a shared object file in a process, but nothing stops me from loading the same library (or a lbrary with the same external definitions) from two different files. Or from both statically linking and dynamically linking the "same" library. In both of those cases it will be observed that the statically-allocated object belongs to the library object and not the process as a whole, often leading to grief.

Comment: @rici: In that case your program has UB (duplicate definitions) and what happens is outside the scope of the C language.

Comment: @rcgldr: No, MSVC is just non-conforming. C specifies static storage; if it uses thread-local storage, the behavior would be observably wrong when you read the object after the thread the function was called in has exited. (E.g. `pthread_exit(localtime(t));`)

Comment: @R - It's the combination of MSVC and Windows. Windows has a per thread data area that exists outside "normal" thread local storage. For example, the seed for rand() is one of the variables kept in the per thread data area. Windows kernel manages the per thread data in a different way than it manages thread local storage. FS (or GS?) may be used to access per thread data or to map the per thread data into a process virtual address space.

Answer (score 0):

The global (defined outside a function) and static (defined inside a function) are allocated once for each **program**. Otherwise, `asctime` would be totally unusable, as you cannot be sure there isn't another program calling that exact function at the same time yours does.